# Custom UIStoryboardSegue using segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to use a custom `UIStoryboardSegue` to implement a transition between two view controllers. I can do this by subclassing `UIStoryboardSegue`, and then setting this class in IB. However, I was looking at the docs which say:

> If your segue does not need to store additional information or provide anything other than a perform method, consider using the segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler: method instead.

Implying that you don't need to create the custom subclass, just use the custom performHandler.

I am confused as to where this code should go, and how I go about using it. Do I create the segue as normal in IB and then override that before it is fired (maybe in shouldPerformSegue: or similar). Elsewhere in apple's documentation it says:

> Your app never creates segue objects directly; they are always created on your behalf by iOS when a segue is triggered

So I don't quite understand why they are then saying to instantiate a segue using a class creator method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The point of `segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:`

- Provide an alternative to `UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` in cases where you also want to create a custom transition, without creating a segue subclass.
- Vend a segue that can be used as the return for `segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier`

As noted above, this approach is only viable for segues which you would call manually -- i.e. not for segues that would otherwise be triggered via IB triggers.

So, for example, if you have a segue that needs to be triggered after a certain timeout period (such as a custom lock-screen), you could use `segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:` to handle the custom transition.

```
-(void)appTimeoutLockScreen
{
    UIStoryboardSegue *segue = 
                [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:@"LockScreenSegue" 
                                                source:sourceVC 
                                           destination:destinationVC 
                                        performHandler:^{
                     // transition code that would 
                     // normally go in the perform method
                }];
    // Dev is responsible for calling prepareForSegue and perform.
    // Note, the order of calls for an IB triggered segue as well as
    // a performSegueWithIdentifier segue is perform first, then
    // prepareForSegue:sender. Manual segues need to inverse the call
    // in order to ensure VC setup is finished before transition.
    [self prepareForSegue:segue sender:self];
    [segue perform];
}
```

Another practical use for the method is unwinding segues. Using a similar scenario
to the previous example, we could use it to return a segue to transition from a lock screen back to the previous viewController:

```
-(UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController*)toVC 
                                     fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fmVC
                                             identifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    UIStoryboardSegue *segue = 
            [UIStoryboardSegue segueWithIdentifier:@"FromLockScreenSegue" 
                                            source:fmVC
                                       destination:toVC 
                                    performHandler:^{
                // transition code
            }];

    return segue;
}
```

Comment: The question is: where do you call that `segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:`? It (presumably) returns a (subclass of) `UIStoryboardSegue`, but then what? There is no `performSegue:` method that takes a `UIStoryboardSegue` instance, just a segue's identifier.

Comment: You can use it when using an unwindingSegue. You can use it for the returning object of -(UIStoryboardSegue *)segueForUnwindingToViewController:(UIViewController *)toViewController fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController identifier:(NSString *)identifier but the question remains as to where or how you would use it for "forward" moving segues.

Comment: I've updated with example code. Calling the class method automatically triggers the segue, there is no need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`. Or more specifically, it's an _alternative_ to calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` in cases where you also want to have a custom transition.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons I must be doing something wrong because I have followed the sample code you gave but the handler is never executed. I put a log in there just to make sure, and nothing happens.

Comment: @daveMac I have a demo app I created a while ago which does this. I'll take a look. Will be a few hours before I can get to it though.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons That would be good if you could. The only way that I can get segueWithIdentifier… to do anything is to use it in the segueForUnwinding… method. But obviously that doesn't do anything for segues going forward.

Comment: Found it. Turns out I was doing a bit more behind the scenes. According to my comments in code, I ran into the exact issue you did -- the segue isn't performed automatically. You are responsible for calling `prepareForSegue:sender` as well as `perform`. I'll add the notes from my code and the extra lines as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46791/discussion-between-michael-g-emmons-and-davemac)

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons For completeness and clarity for future viewers of your answer, will you please edit your answer to include the times when you are using it for an unwinding segue. This is, I believe, a very real world situation that you would use it in often.

Comment: Note that `segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier:` is deprecated as of iOS 9. The documentation suggests using `unwindForSegue:towardsViewController:` instead, but it is a bit different.